# What does SimpleJDBCTemplate.queryForInt do when the database returns null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

What does `SimpleJDBCTemplate.queryForInt` do when the SQL query's actual result is null?

In particular, what happens if I run `queryForInt("select max(foo) from f")` and `f` has no rows?

While I'm on this subject, what happens if I run `queryForInt("select foo from f")` and `f` has no rows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the query returns null, the queryForInt method will return 0.  However, if the query returns no rows, or returns more than one row, queryForInt will throw an IncorrectResultSizeDataAccessException.

[Source](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.0/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForInt(java.lang.String))

Comment: Thanks. I ended up using `coalesce` in the query to ensure that the query always returns a sane default value, rather than letting my client use the 0.